# How to freeze a requirement with pipenv?

Tags: python, pipenv, pipfile

For example we have some pipfile (below) and I'd like to freeze the django version. We don't have a requirements.txt and we only use pipenv. How can I freeze the django version?

```
[[source]]
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"

[packages]
django = "*"

[dev-packages]
black = "*"

[requires]
python_version = "3.6"
```

Answer (score 113, accepted):

Pipenv do natively implement freezing requirements.txt.
It is as simple as:

```
pipenv lock -r > requirements.txt
```

Comment: This method is deprecated, we should use `pipenv requirements > requirements.txt` instead, see https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/advanced/#generating-a-requirements-txt and [ARDVL's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72684458/322283).

Answer (score 119):

As of [v2022.8.13](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/releases/tag/v2022.8.13) of pipenv, the "old" `lock -r` functionality has been removed.

Going forward, this should be accomplished with:

```
pipenv requirements > requirements.txt
```

Comment: This should become the new accepted answer.

Comment: This command leads to `-i https://pypi.org/simple` in requirements.txt
Actually `pipenv run pip freeze > requirements.txt` from https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/3493#issuecomment-1368923539 worked.

Answer (score 34):

Assuming you have your virtual environment activated, you have three simple approaches. I will list them from less verbose to more verbose.

#### pip

```
$ pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

#### pip3

```
$ pip3 freeze > requirements.txt
```

If a virtual environment is active, `pip` is most certainly equivalent to `pip3`.

#### pipenv run

```
$ pipenv run pip freeze > requirements.txt
$ pipenv run pip3 freeze > requirements.txt
```

`pipenv run` spawns a command installed into the virtual environment, so these commands are equivalent to the ones run without `pipenv run`. Once again, it is assumed that your virtual environment is active.

Comment: Please do not use pipenv run pip freeze as it will install all the garbage packages you have installed during your dev

Answer (score 20):

Recent `pipenv` versions (e.g. version 2022.6.7) are using the `requirements` subcommand and `pipenv lock -r` is deprecated.

To freeze default dependencies

```
pipenv requirements > requirements.txt
```

to freeze development dependencies as well

```
pipenv requirements --dev > dev-requirements.txt
```

Answer (score 13):

By using `run` You can run given command from virtualenv, with any arguments forwarded

```
$ pipenv run pip freeze  > requirements.txt
```

Comment: It gave `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory` trying to look for pip file in the .venv directory for the respective project.

Instead following worked for me :
`pipenv run python -m pip freeze > requirements.txt`

Answer (score 2):

```
pipenv run python -m pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

Comment: Please do not use this as it will install all the garbage packages you have installed during your dev

Answer (score 1):

It's as simple as changing `django = "*"` to `django = "your-preferred-version"`. So if you wanted to freeze it to 2.1, the latest release at the time of this writing, you could do this:

```
[packages]
django="2.1"
```

The `pipfile` Git repo has some good examples of different ways to specify version strings: https://github.com/pypa/pipfile#pipfile

Note that when you generate a lockfile from your pipfile, that lockfile is actually the file that's supposed to "freeze" your dependency to a specific version. That way, you don't have to concern yourself with which version works with your code, since by distributing the lockfile everyone else must use the same dependency versions as you. The developers of pipenv intended for developers to use it [like this](https://github.com/pypa/pipfile/issues/7)

Comment: Is there a way to do this through pipenv? Or do I have to open up the pipfile myself?

Comment: That's weird, it's an `==` sign

Comment: This answer did not work for me (regarding the `Pipfile`. What worked for me was `django = "==2.1"`.

Answer (score 1):

Use this as -r flag is deprecated

```
pipenv requirements > requirements.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

first, you ensure that your virtual environment is **active** then you open the terminal and run the command
pip3 freeze > reqirements.txt (pip3)
pip3 freeze > reqirements.txt (pip3)

Answer (score 0):

This is the way that I was prompted by pipenv to generate a requirements.txt file from the project's Pipfile:

```
pipenv lock --requirements
```

Comment: tried this but didn't work
`Error: No such option: --requirements Did you mean --quiet?`

Answer (score -4):

You can create a requirements.txt using this command :

```
pip3 freeze > requirements.txt
```